# Вывод полного контента продуктов в категории woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

По умолчанию в `wordpress` плагин `woocommerce` выводит на страницах категорий товары с таким контентом: миниатюра, название, цена (и иногда кнопку "Добавить в корзину"). Задача стоит такая, что бы на категориях выводились товары с контентом полностью взятым с `content-single-product.php`. У меня получилось правильно вывести (полностью весь контент) через шорткод:

```
[product_page id="1664"]
[product_page id="1665"]
```

но это на отдельной странице, не на категории и это очень не удобно, так как товаров будет очень много. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Comment: Возможно я не прав,но вижу почти идентичные строки с id отличающимся на 1,цикл здесь не подходит что ли?

Comment: Вы правы, я просто показал, что при выводе двух товаров через этот шорткод я добиваюсь нужно результата, но это всего лишь вставляя эти шорткоды на определенную страницу. А нужно такой функционал развернуть на категории. Что за цикл, можно по подробнее, простоите, но я не силен в php.